# Build Error caused by "entry" in webpack configruation

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm actually very new to the ReactJs world and I'm really enjoying it.

So, I went to webpack official website, and I generated a simple webpack configuration on my own, which looks like this:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    "mode": "development",
    "entry": "src/index.js",
    "output": {
        "path": __dirname+'/dist',
        "filename": "[name].[chunkhash:8].js"
    },
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "test": /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                "exclude": /node_modules/,
                //"exclude": [/node_modules/, require.resolve('./index.html')],
                "use": {
                    "loader": "babel-loader",
                    "options": {
                        "presets": [
                            "env",
                            "react"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "test": /\.html$/,
                "use": [
                  {
                    "loader": "html-loader"
                  }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "plugins": [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
          template: "./src/index.html",
          filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
}
```

But then when I run "npm run build", I get an error saying: `Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html`

I kept trying to figure out what the problem was, until I commented out this line in the webpack config: `"entry": "src/index.js"` and "npm run build" worked!

What I want to know is, why? What's wrong with the "entry" part of my configuration? As I said, I'm new to ReactJs, so there's a lot of things I'm still trying to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: please use something like `./src/index.js` see if it works fine ...

Comment: try path **path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')** and make sure webpack is in root directory and it can access ./src/index.js.

Comment: hey! @a_m_dev it works! Thanks! You should put this as an answer so I can tick it. Thanks so much!

Comment: ok then , thanx for accepting and upvoting though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your entry path is not correct and webpack fails to load the file from correct directory. you should use something like:

```
./src/index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using the option `context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src)`, so you'll need to specify your entry as `entry: './index.js'`

the **context** will provide an absolute path, so you will be ready to use relative paths on the **entry** option

[Webpack - Entry and Context](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/)